# Oraclize : Ethereum-bridge on my local private chain

Tags: private-blockchain, testrpc, oracles

I can work with oraclize only using a private chain created with testrpc. 
If I try to use the ethereum-bridge over my locally created private chain it doesn't answer, nether I get message in the ethereum-bridge console.

Actually is it a supported feature or is it only possible to work with private chain created with testrpc?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the steps you have taken? 
Did you deploy the bridge in your private chain in active or broadcast mode?
Are youusing a deterministic OAR?

Comment: Step to reproduce: 
On TestRpc

-Run the TestRpc. 
-Download ethereum-bridge;
-Install ethereum bridge in his folder;
-Run the ethereum bridge with the following command (Active mode): 
` node bridge -H localhost:8545 -a 1 `

-Deploy the using_oraclize contract;
-Deploy the TestOraclizeCall contract;
I'm not using deterministic OAR and I'm uploading the calling contract with the right OAR that the ethereum-bridge console give to me. 
This process works on test rpc. Hovewer, Following the same steps in the private chain (Obviosly chaging the connecting port) is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes! you can use the ethereum-bridge over your locally private chain created by geth or parity,but only on `dev-mode`chain!

After 3 days and a day morning and thanks to the help from @D-Nice @gskapka , I finally solved the problem.I need to put my thoughts together to help guys who may encounter the same problem.
- only support the `dev` geth private network
I am sorry to say that the oraclize(ethereum-bridge) is only supported the `dev`chain , which means you should start your private network using geth like

```
geth --networkid 15 --datadir ./data --rpc --rpcapi "admin,debug,eth,miner,net,personal,txpool,web3" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*"  --dev
```

or simply, you can start you your private network using

```
geth --dev --rpc console
```

- if you deploy the contract using ethereum-bridge on `Non-dev` private network, you will get gas error like

```
gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction in private network
```

so, all the problem is caused by `Non-dev`private network! 
Good luck for you!